# Second fundamental form of cylindrical graphs

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I try to calculate the second fundamental form of cylindrical graphs. Let 
$$
B= \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb R^3  : x_1^2 + x^2_2 =1  \}
$$
is the unit cylinder. Define the height function
$$
u:B\rightarrow \mathbb R^+
$$ 
The cylinderical graph is 
$$
M=
\{
(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in \mathbb R^3 : y_1 = u x_1,~ y_2 = ux_2 ,~ y_3 =x_3 ,~   \forall (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in B
\}
$$

Let $x_1 = \sin \theta  ,~ x_2 =\cos \theta ,~~\theta\in[0,\pi)$. Then we have 
$$
y_\theta= 
(
u_\theta\cos\theta-u\sin\theta,
u_\theta\sin\theta+u\cos\theta,
0
)     \\
y_{x_3}= 
(
u_{x_3}\cos\theta,
u_{x_3}\sin\theta,1
)
$$ 
As general way, I should calculate the normal vector $\nu$ by $y_\theta$ and $y_{x_3}$. And then calculate $y_{\theta\theta}$ , $y_{\theta x_3}$ and $y_{x_3x_3}$. But this a cylinderical graph,  I think 
$$
y_{\theta\theta} \cdot \nu ~~~~~
y_{\theta x_3}\cdot \nu ~~~~~
y_{x_3x_3}\cdot \nu ~~~~~
$$
is not the second fundamental form of $M$, since $(\theta, x_3)$ is not a Eucildean space. So, how should I do ?